# How to change return button to Done in UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, uialertview

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:APP_NAME
                                                message:@"Please enter amount"
                                               delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Done"
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
alert.tag = 2;
[alert show];
```

Above is my coding and type amount in UIAlertView. When keyboard is showing up, my client want "Done" button instead of "Return". Please help me how to do it?

Comment: Are you aware that UIAlertView has been deprecated since iOS 8?

Comment: "Done" button instead of "Return" -- can you explain little bit more

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik when you put cursor in UITextField of UIAlertView, then keyboard will be displayed with Return button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

**UIAlertview**

**Objective-C**

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: APP_NAME message:@"Please enter amount" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Done" otherButtonTitles: nil];
alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
UITextField *textField = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
// set return key type of current textfield
textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
[alert show];
```

**Swift**

```
var alert: UIAlertView = UIAlertView(title: APP_NAME, message: "Please enter amount", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Done", otherButtonTitles: "")
alert.alertViewStyle = .PlainTextInput
var textField: UITextField = alert.textFieldAtIndex(0)
textField.keyboardType = .NumberPad
 textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone
 alert.show()
```

the other type of enum as

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UIReturnKeyType) {
UIReturnKeyDefault,
UIReturnKeyGo,
UIReturnKeyGoogle,
UIReturnKeyJoin,
UIReturnKeyNext,
UIReturnKeyRoute,
UIReturnKeySearch,
UIReturnKeySend,
UIReturnKeyYahoo,
UIReturnKeyDone,
UIReturnKeyEmergencyCall,
UIReturnKeyContinue NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE_IOS(9_0),
};
```

> note -  UIAlertView has been deprecated since iOS 8 in this place use `UIAlertcontroller`

**UIAlertController**

**Swift**

```
 var loginTextField: UITextField?
let alertController = UIAlertController(title:APP_NAME, message: "Please enter amount", preferredStyle: .Alert)
let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "Done", style: .Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
            print("Ok Button Pressed")
        })

alertController.addAction(ok)
alertController.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { (textField) -> Void in
     // Enter the textfiled customization code here.
     loginTextField = textField
     //loginTextField?.placeholder = "xxx"
     loginTextField?.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad
     loginTextField?.returnKeyType = UIReturnKey.Done
        }
presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**Objective-C**

```
 UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:APP_NAME
                                                                     message:@"Please enter amount"
                                                              preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
UIAlertAction *Done = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Done"
                                                      style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                    handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
                                                            // handler code
                                                    }];

[alertController addAction:Done];

[alertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
    //handler code
    textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
// set return key type of current textfield
   textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
}];


[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Try this, in Attribute Inspector, change the Return Key to be "Done"

Comment: , the question is related to UIAlertview textfied returntype, not a common UItextfield return type, can you updated your answer.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik, yours is the right solution. Thanks.

Comment: the reason we can't change the return type on attribute inspector directly , UIalertview does not comes with hierarchy